# Can I shed permissions during a session?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a reporting server which will run certain reports.

The reports are created by me and saved as SQL files.

The reporting application has read/write access, for good reasons.

Is there a way I can deprivilege a SQL session so that when executing the SQL it will use less privileges for execution than the application has available?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Roles to control access to your tables, you can set a "read-only" role after opening the database connection:

```
set role read_only_role;
```

Where this role has select access on the target tables.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-role.html